# Determine the correct calculation to maintain visual exactness between two squares with different centers of rotation

Tags: geometry

I'm encountering this math problem while working on some CSS / JavaScript, so the coordinate system as well as dimensions are noted as such. I've been scratching my head at this for a while and haven't had any luck. Perhaps (hopefully) the solution is more obvious and simple to someone else, so any help / pointers would be very much appreciated.

I basically have two squares that are the same size, position, and rotated the same direction. The only difference between the two squares is the transform-origin property, AKA the center point of the rotation. I'm trying to calculate / figure out what the translation is that I can apply to the blue square so that it's perfectly overlapping the red square. Here's a diagram with some more context:

[image]

Comment: what order did you do the transformations in?

Comment: Just track the position of a vertex of the red square and the position of the corresponding vertex on the blue square, then take the difference.

Comment: The transformations are applied as single declarations in CSS